# I provided Random Seeds to an existing answer, but my edit was rejected. Why?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/396288/how-do-i-get-the-new-pets-orby-and-asmody/396323#396323) mentions that you "will need to keep restarting until it appears." because it is a "rare node". I have provided the Game Seed that you can enter, so you are not dependent on RNG. I feel this is quite helpful, because you don't have to restart over and over again, until it works.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps your edit to the answer adds context that the author did not intend to have, or it ruins the spirit of that answer. In this case, I would recommend creating your own answer to the question, and adding your details there. Your answer may not get accepted, but additional info in the form of a separate answer is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 3):

nightsurfer's points are certainly true.  I also think in this case, [your edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/317766) made more sense as a comment on the answer rather than an edit.  My reason for this is because of what nightsurfer said:

> Perhaps your edit to the answer adds context that the author did not intend to have, or it ruins the spirit of that answer